# Micro SD Card Reader Slot Not Working (HP Stream 14-z010nr does not detect)

Tags: drivers, hp, card-reader, micro-sd, emmc

The Micro SD slot on my computer is not working.
Model no of my PC is: J9V55UA - [more info here](https://support.hp.com/us-en/document/c04425693#AbT1)

The computer only has 32GB of eMMC memory (No HDD or SSD), therefore using an external memory card is very important for me.  I was using Ubuntu 17.04, and it was working, then without any reason, the microSD card was not detected anymore.

Then I installed Ubuntu 17.10 and it started working, but after some time it stopped working again, and I don't know why.  I don't want to reinstall Ubuntu.

```
$ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 064e:c342 Suyin Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 0438:7900 Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0a5c:216d Broadcom Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0438:7900 Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
$ sudo lshw -C storage
      *-storage                 
       açıklama: SATA controller
       ürün: FCH SATA Controller [AHCI mode]
       üretici: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
       physical id: 11
       bus info: pci@0000:00:11.0
       sürüm: 40
       genişlik: 32 bits
       saat: 66MHz
       kapasiteler: storage pm msi ahc__1.0 bus_master cap_list
       yapılandırma: driver=ahci latency=32
       kaynaklar: irq:30 ioport:f140(boyut=8) ioport:f130(boyut=4) ioport:f120(boyut=8) ioport:f110(boyut=4) ioport:f100(boyut=16) bellek:fea6f000-fea6f3ff
  *-scsi
       physical id: 1
       mantıksal ad: scsi0
       kapasiteler: emulated
$ sudo dmesg | tail -n 100
[  299.173766] sdhci: =========== REGISTER DUMP (mmc0)===========
[  299.173775] sdhci: Sys addr: 0x00000000 | Version:  0x00001002
[  299.173784] sdhci: Blk size: 0x00007040 | Blk cnt:  0x00000001
[  299.173791] sdhci: Argument: 0x00000000 | Trn mode: 0x00000013
[  299.173799] sdhci: Present:  0x01ff0207 | Host ctl: 0x00000017
[  299.173806] sdhci: Power:    0x0000000f | Blk gap:  0x00000000
[  299.173813] sdhci: Wake-up:  0x00000000 | Clock:    0x00000007
[  299.173820] sdhci: Timeout:  0x0000000a | Int stat: 0x00000000
[  299.173827] sdhci: Int enab: 0x02ff008b | Sig enab: 0x02ff008b
[  299.173834] sdhci: AC12 err: 0x00000000 | Slot int: 0x000000ff
[  299.173841] sdhci: Caps:     0x21fec8b2 | Caps_1:   0x00002573
[  299.173848] sdhci: Cmd:      0x0000133a | Max curr: 0x00c80064
[  299.173853] sdhci: Host ctl2: 0x0000801b
[  299.173862] sdhci: ADMA Err: 0x00000000 | ADMA Ptr: 0x34521208
[  299.173866] sdhci: ===========================================
[  309.412663] mmc0: Timeout waiting for hardware interrupt.
[  309.412677] sdhci: =========== REGISTER DUMP (mmc0)===========
[  309.412685] sdhci: Sys addr: 0x00000000 | Version:  0x00001002
[  309.412692] sdhci: Blk size: 0x00007040 | Blk cnt:  0x00000001
[  309.412698] sdhci: Argument: 0x00000000 | Trn mode: 0x00000013
[  309.412705] sdhci: Present:  0x01ff0207 | Host ctl: 0x00000017
[  309.412711] sdhci: Power:    0x0000000f | Blk gap:  0x00000000
[  309.412717] sdhci: Wake-up:  0x00000000 | Clock:    0x00000007
[  309.412722] sdhci: Timeout:  0x0000000a | Int stat: 0x00000000
[  309.412728] sdhci: Int enab: 0x02ff008b | Sig enab: 0x02ff008b
[  309.412734] sdhci: AC12 err: 0x00000000 | Slot int: 0x000000ff
[  309.412740] sdhci: Caps:     0x21fec8b2 | Caps_1:   0x00002573
[  309.412746] sdhci: Cmd:      0x0000133a | Max curr: 0x00c80064
[  309.412751] sdhci: Host ctl2: 0x0000801b
[  309.412757] sdhci: ADMA Err: 0x00000000 | ADMA Ptr: 0x34521208
[  309.412760] sdhci: ===========================================
[  319.651573] mmc0: Timeout waiting for hardware interrupt.
[  319.651591] sdhci: =========== REGISTER DUMP (mmc0)===========
[  319.651600] sdhci: Sys addr: 0x00000000 | Version:  0x00001002
[  319.651608] sdhci: Blk size: 0x00007040 | Blk cnt:  0x00000001
[  319.651616] sdhci: Argument: 0x00000000 | Trn mode: 0x00000013
[  319.651623] sdhci: Present:  0x01ff0207 | Host ctl: 0x00000017
[  319.651630] sdhci: Power:    0x0000000f | Blk gap:  0x00000000
[  319.651637] sdhci: Wake-up:  0x00000000 | Clock:    0x00000007
[  319.651644] sdhci: Timeout:  0x0000000a | Int stat: 0x00000000
[  319.651651] sdhci: Int enab: 0x02ff008b | Sig enab: 0x02ff008b
[  319.651657] sdhci: AC12 err: 0x00000000 | Slot int: 0x000000ff
[  319.651664] sdhci: Caps:     0x21fec8b2 | Caps_1:   0x00002573
[  319.651671] sdhci: Cmd:      0x0000133a | Max curr: 0x00c80064
[  319.651677] sdhci: Host ctl2: 0x0000801b
[  319.651684] sdhci: ADMA Err: 0x00000000 | ADMA Ptr: 0x34521208
[  319.651688] sdhci: ===========================================
[  329.890546] mmc0: Timeout waiting for hardware interrupt.
[  329.890563] sdhci: =========== REGISTER DUMP (mmc0)===========
[  329.890572] sdhci: Sys addr: 0x00000000 | Version:  0x00001002
[  329.890580] sdhci: Blk size: 0x00007040 | Blk cnt:  0x00000001
[  329.890588] sdhci: Argument: 0x00000000 | Trn mode: 0x00000013
[  329.890595] sdhci: Present:  0x01ff0207 | Host ctl: 0x00000017
[  329.890602] sdhci: Power:    0x0000000f | Blk gap:  0x00000000
[  329.890609] sdhci: Wake-up:  0x00000000 | Clock:    0x00000007
[  329.890616] sdhci: Timeout:  0x0000000a | Int stat: 0x00000000
[  329.890623] sdhci: Int enab: 0x02ff008b | Sig enab: 0x02ff008b
[  329.890629] sdhci: AC12 err: 0x00000000 | Slot int: 0x000000ff
[  329.890636] sdhci: Caps:     0x21fec8b2 | Caps_1:   0x00002573
[  329.890643] sdhci: Cmd:      0x0000133a | Max curr: 0x00c80064
[  329.890649] sdhci: Host ctl2: 0x0000801b
[  329.890656] sdhci: ADMA Err: 0x00000000 | ADMA Ptr: 0x34521208
[  329.890660] sdhci: ===========================================
[  340.129485] mmc0: Timeout waiting for hardware interrupt.
[  340.129498] sdhci: =========== REGISTER DUMP (mmc0)===========
[  340.129504] sdhci: Sys addr: 0x00000000 | Version:  0x00001002
[  340.129510] sdhci: Blk size: 0x00007040 | Blk cnt:  0x00000001
[  340.129515] sdhci: Argument: 0x00000000 | Trn mode: 0x00000013
[  340.129520] sdhci: Present:  0x01ff0207 | Host ctl: 0x00000017
[  340.129525] sdhci: Power:    0x0000000f | Blk gap:  0x00000000
[  340.129530] sdhci: Wake-up:  0x00000000 | Clock:    0x00000007
[  340.129534] sdhci: Timeout:  0x0000000a | Int stat: 0x00000000
[  340.129539] sdhci: Int enab: 0x02ff008b | Sig enab: 0x02ff008b
[  340.129544] sdhci: AC12 err: 0x00000000 | Slot int: 0x000000ff
[  340.129549] sdhci: Caps:     0x21fec8b2 | Caps_1:   0x00002573
[  340.129554] sdhci: Cmd:      0x0000133a | Max curr: 0x00c80064
[  340.129557] sdhci: Host ctl2: 0x0000801b
[  340.129562] sdhci: ADMA Err: 0x00000000 | ADMA Ptr: 0x34521208
[  340.129564] sdhci: ===========================================
[  341.755377] mmc0: Card removed during transfer!
[  341.755392] mmc0: Resetting controller.
[  341.837468] sdhci-pci 0000:00:14.7: no tuning point found
[  341.837485] mmc0: tuning execution failed: -5
[  341.837504] mmc0: error -5 whilst initialising SD card
[  376.477760] mmc0: Timeout waiting for hardware interrupt.
[  376.477777] sdhci: =========== REGISTER DUMP (mmc0)===========
[  376.477786] sdhci: Sys addr: 0x00000000 | Version:  0x00001002
[  376.477794] sdhci: Blk size: 0x00007040 | Blk cnt:  0x00000001
[  376.477802] sdhci: Argument: 0x00000000 | Trn mode: 0x00000013
[  376.477809] sdhci: Present:  0x01ff0207 | Host ctl: 0x00000017
[  376.477816] sdhci: Power:    0x0000000f | Blk gap:  0x00000000
[  376.477823] sdhci: Wake-up:  0x00000000 | Clock:    0x00000007
[  376.477830] sdhci: Timeout:  0x0000000a | Int stat: 0x00000000
[  376.477837] sdhci: Int enab: 0x02ff008b | Sig enab: 0x02ff008b
[  376.477844] sdhci: AC12 err: 0x00000000 | Slot int: 0x000000ff
[  376.477851] sdhci: Caps:     0x21fec8b2 | Caps_1:   0x00002573
[  376.477857] sdhci: Cmd:      0x0000133a | Max curr: 0x00c80064
[  376.477863] sdhci: Host ctl2: 0x0000801b
[  376.477870] sdhci: ADMA Err: 0x00000000 | ADMA Ptr: 0x34521208
[  376.477874] sdhci: ===========================================
```

Comment: Could you please [edit] your question to include the output of `lsusb` and `sudo lshw -C storage`? When you plug the memory card into the card reader and wait 10–30 seconds, what's the output of `sudo dmesg | tail -n 100`? You can either 1) select, copy & paste the terminal content or 2) [save the program output to a file](//askubuntu.com/q/420981/175814) and use that. Longer listings (the editor will tell you what's too long) should be uploaded to a [pastie service](https://paste.ubuntu.com/) and linked to in the question. Thanks.

Comment: 17.10 is not out yet... did you mean 16.10?

Comment: No I use Preview Version of 17.10. Same problem happened also with 16.10, 17,04 etc.. I don't know why. Micro sd disappears after some time.

Comment: Thanks! The kernel appears to think that the memory card was removed shortly after insertion each time. That looks like a kernel bug that you should report [on Launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/). Unfortunately bug reports are off topic here.

Comment: The problem was because that I clicked "software & updates, developer options, not approved updates"